# Is Oracle application server OC4J bundled with oracle database driver ojdbc14.jar?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oc4j

I have webapp that connect to oracle DB via JDBC and used class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

Need I  to package my webapp with ojdbc14.jar if it will be run in OC4J container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OC4J comes with an JDBC driver jar. Oracle documentation provides instructions for upgrading it to a newer version or to a third party JDBC driver.